# How Fill UIView on main ViewController with another View?

Tags: iphone, uiview

HI gurus,
How i can fill the UIView on main VC with another VC, i make simple ipadd app, on main view i have 2 button and 2 UIview, one view is Main UIview and Main UIView have UIview again that i want replace with another NIB (UIViewController). if i klick button 1 UIview will be fill NIB1 and if i klick buton 2 UIView will be fill NIB2

This is main .h

```
#import "nib1.h"
#import "nib2.h"

@interface multinibViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *topview;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *topview;

-(IBAction)changeNib1;
-(IBAction)changeNib2;
@end
```

This is implementation  what code i must be fill  ?

```
 -(IBAction)changeNib1{

    }

    -(IBAction)changeNib2{

    }
```

what can I do to be like this ?
Thanks,
Updated : 
The page ipad layout like this

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|   This is MainViewController                               |
|   button 1            button 2                             |
|                                                            |
|  |------------------------------------------------------|  |
|  |          This UIView that i want load                |  |
|  |     from another NIB / UIViewContoller               |  |
|  |                                                      |  |
|  |                                                      |  |
|  |                                                      |  |
|  |                                                      |  |
|  |------------------------------------------------------|  |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
|   lable  Annother_button   Annother_Object                 |
|                                                            |
.                                                            .
.                                                            .
.                                                            .
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Thanks skorulis, thats work, use this code

```
UIViewController *nib1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib1" bundle:nil];
    [self.topview addSubview:nib1.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the UINavigationController. The basic idea of it is to navigate between UIViewControllers which seems to be what you're trying to do.

Edit:
Try doing this in nib 1.

```
UIViewController n2 = [[nib2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:n2.view];
```

Just make sure the background color of the second nib is clear so you can see what is behind.

Comment: Hi skorulis thanks for reply, i have try uinaviagtionvontroller, this way make main UIviewController be hide, i want  on mainViewcontroller have UIView and many object, this UIView is half of page that i want fill with another uiviewcontroller, so mainUIviewCOntroller still view on page.

Comment: Hi Skorulis, this code is warning/error UIViewController *nib2 = [[nib2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; (Methode -alloc notfound)

Comment: Hi Skorulis, i have update my question, this way is success, but how i delegated this view to main view ?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally made the variable the same as the class. I'm not quite sure what you mean by delegate this to the main view.

Comment: i mean, how i can parsing data from Nib2 to MainVC ?, i make @protocol on nib2 but nib1.delegate is does not exist. any other way ?